# cpp: eclipse doesn't recognize 'long long' type

Tags: c++, linux, long-long

I have some where in my code the next line:
    long long maxCPUTime=4294967296;

(the largest number long type can be is 4294967296 -1 , so I used long long)

the problem is, when I compile ,I get the next error:

```
error: integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type
```

Its as if, eclips doesn't  recognize that I wrote 'long long' and it thinks I wrote 'long'.

(I'm using linux os)

anyone knows why I get this error?

Comment: Not familiar with eclipse, but if it was me, I'd try `int64_t` or `uint64_t` for the type.

Comment: @Mr Lister: the type of the variable is not a problem here.

Comment: @kakush Won't you accept one of the answers?

Answer (score 6):

Append `LL` to it:

```
long long maxCPUTime = 4294967296LL;
```

That should solve the problem. (`LL` is preferred over `ll` as it's easier to distinguish.)

`long long` wasn't officially added to the standard until C99/C++11.

Normally, integer literals will have the minimum type to hold it. But prior to C99/C++11, `long long` didn't "exist" in the standard. (but most compilers had it as an extension) So therefore (under some compilers) integer literals larger than `long` don't get the `long long` type.

Comment: Doesn't `ull` mean `unsigned long long`, while he wants a `long long`?

Comment: As a tip: Use capital `L` rather than lowercase `l`. Both compile, but for humans, `L` is easier to distinguish (in most fonts) from `1`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your constant (4294967296) doesn't fit into `int` and `unsigned int` (actually it doesn't fit into `long` as well - that's what compiler is saying) and is not automatically promoted to `long long`, thus the error. You have to add the suffix `LL` (or `ll` although the latter may be confused by short-sighted people like me for `11`) to make it `long long`:

```
long long maxCPUTime = 4294967296LL;
```